# How to make object in loop in js with external value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to make a jqgrid Column dynamically. But i m facing a problem "closure on a variable modified in loop of outer scope". Here is my function that return the colModel of jqgrid.

```
 var getJqgridColModel = function () {
            var colModel = [
            ];
           //Here i am making the column
            if (args && args.colModel) {

                for (var i = 0; i < args.colModel.length; i++) {

                    var col = {
                        name: "action",
                        width: "100",
                        sortable: false,
                        hidden: false,

                        formatter: function(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
                            var markup = "<a class=\"jqGrid-Column-Text\" title=\"%ToolTip%\" href=%Href%;>%Text%</a>";
                            var replacements = {
//Here is problem
                                "%Text%": args.colModel[i].actionLink,//Problem occures here.This "args.colModel[i].actionLink" is not recoginize.It shows "closure on a variable modified in loop of outer scope"
                                "%ToolTip%": "//",
                                "%Href%": "javascript:PersonSearch.perfomeActionOnSelect(" + rowObject.PersonLog.PersonId + ")"
                            };

                            markup = markup.replace(/%\w+%/g, function(all) {
                                return replacements[all];
                            });
                            return markup;
                        }
                    };
                    colModel.push(col);
                }

            }

            return colModel;
        }
```

How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your original example did not work is that all the closures you created in the loop referenced the same frame.

```
    var getJqgridColModel = function () {
    var colModel = [];
    //Here i am making the column
    if (args && args.colModel) {
                for (var i = 0; i < args.colModel.length; i++) {

                    var col = {
                        name: "action",
                        width: "100",
                        sortable: false,
                        hidden: false,

                        formatter: (function(i){
                            return function(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
                                var markup = "<a class=\"jqGrid-Column-Text\" title=\"%ToolTip%\" href=%Href%;>%Text%</a>";
                                var replacements = {
                                    //Here is problem
                                    "%Text%": args.colModel[i].actionLink,//Problem occures here.This "args.colModel[i].actionLink" is not recoginize.It shows "closure on a variable modified in loop of outer scope"
                                    "%ToolTip%": "//",
                                    "%Href%": "javascript:PersonSearch.perfomeActionOnSelect(" + rowObject.PersonLog.PersonId + ")"
                                };

                                markup = markup.replace(/%\w+%/g, function(all) {
                                        return replacements[all];
                                });
                                return markup;
                            }
                        }(i));
                    };
                    colModel.push(col);
                }

        }

        return colModel;
}
```